# Odd incompatibility between multi-line forest nodes and tabular

Tags: tables, trees, forest

The following MWE compiles just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

%\begin{tabular}{c}
  \begin{forest}
    [x\\y, align=center
      [z]
    ] 
  \end{forest}
%\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

However, if the commented lines are un-commented, an error results:

```
! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.11   \end{forest}
```

The error is not consistent across cases. Sometimes the compiler complains like so:

```
Use of \@argarraycr doesn't match its definition.
```

On the other hand, the following code -- which retains the `tabular` environment but gets rid of the node under the multi-line node -- compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \begin{forest}
    [x\\y, align=center
      %[z]
    ] 
  \end{forest}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Somewhat oddly, I have never experienced this sort of error prior to a week ago. I update using `tlmgr` fairly regularly, so I would guess some update in some package somewhere is to blame. But I wouldn't venture a guess as to which. Replacing all occurrences of `\\` with `\protect\\` does resolve the error, but this still seems like a bug, since it is new behavior.

Comment: I can confirm the problem using forest.sty   `2015/07/15 v1.09 Drawing (linguistic) trees` Using an older version doen't produce the error.

Comment: I think the following is related: `[\phantom{x}[y]]` produces an error inside a `forest`, but neither `[\protect\phantom{x}[y]]` nor `[\phantom{x}]` do.

Comment: This seems, indeed, like a bug. You should contact the package author (he might also see this question here, but an e-mail might be quicker).

Comment: Well, this is a funny bug, in my opinion. I have forgotten to remove a debug statement when releasing v1.09. Can you please confirm that removing line 2580 from forest.sty (... `DEBUG calign` ...) solves the problem?

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Hi. Yes, I can confirn that removing that line solves the problem.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Many thanks, that appears to resolve the issue. Would you care to enter this as an answer?

Comment: Great! I will (a bit later), and I'll also post a new version to ctan.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović 1.10 is now available for TeX Live via the update manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced into `forest` v1.09. It is fixed in v1.0.10, which is available on ctan.

The bug is due to a leftover debugging statement, which issues a `\typeout` command, whose argument contains (after expansion) a `\\` in the above non-working example.

Now, this is normally not a problem: having `\typeout{\\}` in the main body of a document is just fine. However, some environments redefine `\\` in such a way that it is un-`\typeout`able (e.g. `tabular` or `flushleft`): having `\typeout{\\}` inside such an environment will produce weird errors.

The working example above worked because the offending `\typeout` statement is run (in `forest` v1.09) only for nodes with exactly one child.